# Customize XML layout editor Android Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I was wondering if there was a way to customize the Android XML editor, for example with the drag and drop editor; is there a way to choose the preset textsize in textviews?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to create presets in the XML Editor, but if you use [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) you can change TextView's default `textSize` attribute and almost any other characteristic.

Comment: yes I know that I could do that but that is not very transferable, and it takes a decent amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. What is it you would like to set them to?

(Note that you can multiselect all the text views, then go to the property sheet and set the size there, and it will apply to all.)